# Not able to list broker id in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a docker-compose file.

```
 version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test-topic:5:2"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I am running 2 brokers with

```
 docker-compose scale kafka=2
```

Now i want to get the id of broker by running this file in docker bash of kafka

```
 zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 ls /brokers/ids
```

All i am getting is:-

```
    Connecting to localhost:2181
KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /brokers/ids
```

But i am able to consume and produce the message, any idea why this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying `localhost` but Zookeeper is on a separate container from Kafka.

Try:

```
➜ docker exec -it tmp_kafka_1 zookeeper-shell.sh zookeeper:2181 ls /brokers/ids
Connecting to zookeeper:2181

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[1001]
```

Also note that `docker-compose scale kafka=2` does not bring up the second broker - it fails during startup with

```
kafka_2      | [2020-04-28 14:55:19,104] ERROR [KafkaServer id=1002] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka_2      | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Configured end points localhost:9092 in advertised listeners are already registered by broker 1001
```

If you want an example of Docker Compose running multiple brokers check out [this one](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.3.1-post/examples/kafka-cluster/docker-compose.yml).

Comment: I was following this `http://wurstmeister.github.io/kafka-docker/`, I am not getting the error about the `scale` though, plus what should be my advertised listener, if it's in different container ?

Comment: Plus is there any docs where I can find the parameters to specify,  ` zookeeper-shell.sh <what should be this/> ls /brokers/ids`, basically, I blindly copied the code, without understanding.

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve? I've already linked to a Docker Compose that shows how to run multiple brokers correctly.

Comment: Ok let me go through it. Thanks